# How to find a specific href with beautiful soup Pyhton?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to find a specific href in this html :

```
<div class="lister-item mode-advanced">
<div class="lister-top-right">
<div class="ribbonize" data-caller="filmosearch" data-tconst="tt10665338"></div>
</div>
<div class="lister-item-image float-left">
<a href="/title/tt10665338/"> <img alt="Halloween Kills" class="loadlate" data-tconst="tt10665338" height="98" loadlate="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2RmMGY2Y2UtNjA1NS00NGE4LThiNzItMmE1NTk5NzI5NmE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjY1MTg4Mzc@._V1_UX67_CR0,0,67,98_AL_.jpg" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/sash/4FyxwxECzL-U1J8.png" width="67"/>
</a> </div>
<div class="lister-item-content">
<h3 class="lister-item-header">
<span class="lister-item-index unbold text-primary">100.</span>
<a href="/title/tt10665338/">Halloween Kills</a>
<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">(2021)</span>
</h3>
<p class="text-muted">
<span class="certificate">R</span>
<span class="ghost">|</span>
<span class="runtime">105 min</span>
<span class="ghost">|</span>
<span class="genre">
Horror, Thriller            </span>
</p>
<div class="ratings-bar">
<div class="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating" data-value="5.5" name="ir">
<span class="global-sprite rating-star imdb-rating"></span>
<strong>5.5</strong>
</div>
<div class="inline-block ratings-user-rating">
<span class="userRatingValue" data-tconst="tt10665338" id="urv_tt10665338">
<span class="global-sprite rating-star no-rating"></span>
<span class="rate" data-no-rating="Rate this" data-value="0" name="ur">Rate this</span>
</span>
<div class="starBarWidget" id="sb_tt10665338">
<div class="rating rating-list" data-csrf-token="" data-ga-identifier="" data-starbar-class="rating-list" data-user="" id="tt10665338|imdb|5.5|5.5|adv_li_tt||advsearch|title" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" title="Users rated this 5.5/10 (79,114 votes) - click stars to rate">
<meta content="5.5" itemprop="ratingValue"/>
<meta content="10" itemprop="bestRating"/>
<meta content="79114" itemprop="ratingCount"/>
<span class="rating-bg"> </span>
<span class="rating-imdb" style="width: 77px"> </span>
<span class="rating-stars">
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>1</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>2</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>3</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>4</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>5</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>6</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>7</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>8</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>9</span></a>
<a href="/register/login?why=vote" rel="nofollow" title="Register or login to rate this title"><span>10</span></a>
</span>
<span class="rating-rating"><span class="value">5.5</span><span class="grey">/</span><span class="grey">10</span></span>
<span class="rating-cancel"><a href="/title/tt10665338/vote" rel="nofollow" title="Delete"><span>X</span></a></span>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="inline-block ratings-metascore">
<span class="metascore mixed">42        </span>
        Metascore
            </div>
</div>
<p class="text-muted">
Surviving victims of Michael Myers form a vigilante mob and vow to end his reign of terror after they discover that he is still alive.</p>
<p class="">
    Director:
<a href="/name/nm0337773/">David Gordon Green</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000130/">Jamie Lee Curtis</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0339460/">Judy Greer</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm5506858/">Andi Matichak</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0183921/">James Jude Courtney</a>
</p>
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
<span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
<span data-value="79114" name="nv">79,114</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to find the director, it would be David Gordon Green

I can find the class with :

```
container.find_all('p', {"class":""} )
```

i get :

```
<p class="">
     Director:
 <a href="/name/nm0337773/">David Gordon Green</a>
 <span class="ghost">|</span> 
     Stars:
 <a href="/name/nm0000130/">Jamie Lee Curtis</a>, 
 <a href="/name/nm0339460/">Judy Greer</a>, 
 <a href="/name/nm5506858/">Andi Matichak</a>, 
 <a href="/name/nm0183921/">James Jude Courtney</a>
 </p>
```

or i can get :

```
container.find_all("a", href = "/name/nm0337773/")
```

to find :

```
[<a href="/name/nm0337773/">David Gordon Green</a>]
```

but it's too specific, since I would like to webscrap.

In fact, i would like to find the first href under the class Director.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: `container.find_all("a")` returns a list of all the `a` tags so doing `container.find_all("a")[0]` will give you the first element but it will throw error if the list is empty

Answer (score 1):

You could select by `:-soup-contains("Director:")` and pick the next `<a>`:

```
soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Director:") a')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p class="text-muted">
Surviving victims of Michael Myers form a vigilante mob and vow to end his reign of terror after they discover that he is still alive.</p>
<p class="">
    Director:
<a href="/name/nm0337773/">David Gordon Green</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000130/">Jamie Lee Curtis</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0339460/">Judy Greer</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm5506858/">Andi Matichak</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0183921/">James Jude Courtney</a>
</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("Director:") a')
```